# Instruction sequence that does the same thing as push

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-16

I would like to know if it is possible (and if so, how) to write a sequence of instructions that would have the same effect as `push`. For example, if the contents of `ax` is 1200 , and I do a `push ax`, what other instructions can I use to accomplish what `push ax` does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some other answers use `[sp]` for stack addressing, but it is not possible in 16-bit mode, nor in 32-bit or 64-bit modes either. However, in 32-bit mode you can use `[esp]` and in x86-64 you can use `[rsp]` for memory addressing, but in 16-bit mode there is no memory addressing that uses `sp`. See [here](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm16.htm) for possible memory addressing modes in 16-bit mode.

So, what you need to do: store the value of `bp` somewhere, copy `sp` into `bp`, then use `bp` for addressing the stack, and finally restore the original value of `bp`.

If you have a place where to store `bp`, that's easy (this is in YASM/NASM syntax):

```
mov [bp_storage], bp
sub sp,2
mov bp,sp
mov [bp],ax
mov bp,[bp_storage]

...

bp_storage dw 0
```

Using a register instead of memory address like `bp_storage` here is trivial too.

**Edit:** Added version that does not modify flags (below), as `push` doesn't modify flags either.

The code above modifies flags, whereas `push ax` does not modify any flags. That can be solved by storing first `ah` into memory, then loading flags into `ah` with `lahf`, then  storing the flags from `ah` to memory, then modifying the stack as above, and then afterwards restoring flags from memory via `ah` by using `sahf` and finally restoring `ah` from memory.

**Edit:** To simulate `push ax` without changes in flags, `ah` must be saved before `lahf` and loaded before `mov [bp],ax`. Fixed.

```
mov [ah_storage],ah
lahf
mov [flags_storage],ah
mov [bp_storage],bp
sub sp,2
mov bp,sp
mov ah,[ah_storage]
mov [bp],ax
mov bp,[bp_storage]
mov ah,[flags_storage]
sahf
mov ah,[ah_storage]

...

bp_storage    dw 0
ah_storage    db 0
flags_storage db 0
```

[`sub`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/sub.html) modifies `AF`, `CF`, `OF`, `PF`, `SF`, `ZF`, whereas [`lahf`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/lahf.html) loads and [`sahf`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/sahf.html) stores only `AF`, `CF`, `PF`, `SF`, `ZF` (no `OF`). However, `sp` should never overflow in normal stack usage.

But, if you can't access memory, and want to use stack to store `bp` you can do that, but if you neither have free registers to use, things get complicated. But if you are using a real mode OS, you can block interrupts with `cli`, exchange `bp` and `sp`, use `bp` for stack addressing, exchange `bp` and `sp` again and allow interrupts again with `sti`.

**Edit:** the value of `sp` needs to subtracted by 2 to simulate `push ax`. Fixed. This version does not modify flags (except interrupt flag).

```
cli
xchg bp,sp
lea bp,[bp-2]
mov [bp],ax
xchg bp,sp
sti
```

Answer (score 2):

At least if memory serves, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
sub sp, 2
mov [sp], ax
```

Comment: Didn't down vote you, but a simple dec won't cover the size of the above write.  You need a subtract or something similiar.

Comment: Now it's better, but `ax` is a word, so `dec sp` two times

Comment: `mov [sp], ax` is invalid. There is no such instruction in x86. `esp` and `rsp` can be used for memory addressing, `sp` can not. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract a value that equals the size of the data write required from the sp, then move/write on the stack the objects you want.  Compilers do this sort of thing all the time.  Look at a -S output for examples.  Beware of atomic/thread issues if you do this...

Comment: On embedded systems, you play with a stack pointer in a non atomic way and things go boom.  "move stack pointer", interrupt, push info, return, "write info", boom.

Comment: BTW, I've upvoted the other answers as they include actual sample code whereas I was lazy and did not :)

Comment: I think that as long as you remember that memory above SP may be trashed at any moment, you're safe on embedded systems too. As long as interrupt saves and restores SP properly, I can't see how "adjust esp reserving a word on top, store data on top" scenario can be broken.

Comment: Call it me being extra paranoid then.  I've been burned quite enough by 2 seperate instructions doing a single write to memory and having somethign else come along in the middle and muck things up.

Answer (score 1):

If I've not forgotten the Intel syntax:

```
lea sp, [sp-2]
mov [sp], ax
```

I've used `lea` to avoid touching `FLAGS` (neither `push` nor `mov` or `lea` touch them, but `sub` and `dec` do).

**EDIT:** It turns out that I've forgotten more important thing: there is no `[sp]` addressing mode. The correct answer is the one by @nrz, mine could be applied to `esp` and `eax` (would be `lea esp,[esp-4]`) on 80386 and above.

Comment: `mov [sp], ax` is invalid. There is no such instruction in x86. `esp` and `rsp` can be used for memory addressing, `sp` can not. See my answer.